# MB ML 320 wont go past 60 mps and vibrates

Tags: ml320

It started yesterday when I started to do above 60 mps, it wont go past 60 but if you paddle gas more, it will vibrate, but wont go beyond 60. When applying brake it will push to go forward, like dont want to stop.

Comment: Do you actually mean MPH (miles per hour)? MPS implies *miles per second* to me ... or is it meters per second? It sounds as though the car may be in "limp home mode" or whatever MB calls it. Any check engine lights (CEL) lit? If there is a CEL, get it read to have more information about what's going on. What year and how many miles on the car?

Answer (score 1):

> When applying brake it will push to go forward, like dont want to stop.

That sure *sounds* like a large problem, and whatever is causing it is putting your ML 320 in [limp mode](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mercedes+ml320+limp+mode), where speed (among other things) are electronically limited.

Take it to Mercedes mechanic!  Those are not simple vehicles, and computer diagnostics for them are a different animal than for most cars.